# Exporting Template Project VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have solution with four projects:

Data,
UI.Controls,
Application and
**ViSoft**

**ViSoft** is currently referencing the three other projects through "References->Projects-> Solutions".
I am also referencing both MVVM Ligth and Entity Framework through Nuget Package Manager.

Now i want to create a project template of the **ViSoft** application for the third party user.

I tried "File->Export Template->Project Template"

When i go to try the newly created templates and build the project, the nuget packages are loaded but the references to Data, UI.Controls and Application are missing.

How can I create the template so the assemblies are bundled into the template?

This is a WPF app if it mathers.

Comment: You can create an item or a project template. I think there is no way to generate a template from multiple projects.